# How to create new screen in maximo anywhere app

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have maximo anywhere code base, i would like to create new screen. Please let me know how can i start. I have added new view inside app.xml as below
 How we can identify where to place this view?

Comment: <view id="WorkExecution.TestView" label="TestView" saveonshow="true" showBackButton="false"></view>

Answer (score 0):

Look at transitionTo, that's typically how we launch these subviews.  Take a look at these examples in our documentation:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.2/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.2/config_apps/t_add_rel_records.html?lang=en